# Internet Explorer 6 <select> Causing Repaint/Redraw/Flash of Screen

Tags: internet-explorer-6

I have a large page (greater than 3000 elements). On this page, I have a couple of <select> elements. While the page is loading, there is an overlay that appears over the page. When the page has finished loading, I can clearly see that the <select> elements are not yet visible. Suddenly, the page goes completely blank (minus the background color), and there exists a rectangular box where the <select> elements should exist. Then, the page redraws itself and everything is fine. I am trying to determine the cause of this. Unfortunately, I cannot provide a link to an example page, as I am unable to reproduce this issue. However, it appears to be a combination of large DOM structure plus IE6 plus <select> elements that appears to cause this. I must support IE6, so ditching the browser is not an option. Any insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the select elements I am using tend to have a style property set with the width set to around 100 pixels. I thought that if I also set the size="1" property, this could correct the rendering issue, but it does not appear to work.

Comment: Do you have an example page to share with you, Nickisi?